# I am very dizzy! Somebody help me with my Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, blender, webgl

This is a pretty long question and is much of my 2 week history. Please bare with me and help me out of this.

As the question states I am now feeling dizzy after struggling with my ubuntu machine from the last 4 days. I accept that should have posted a question here first, but being a windows user and newbie to Linux even to ask questions I lacked some understanding. Hence after one good week of struggle with linux and learning few things about it here I come to ask the question.

### Specs

- Linux - Installed Ubuntu 12.10 (but says 13.04 in the about menu)
- Machine - Dell PWS 450 Board - Intel chipset
- Graphics Card - Nvidia quadro fx 1000
- RAM - 3 GB DDR
- Dual monitors to support Stereoscopy (I work in my University Lab, where a machine has been given to me for testing the robotics software using Ubuntu)
- Desktop environment - GNOME (sorry but Unity sucks for me)

### Problems

Video card problem - Login Screen, Blender and WebGL (not working fine)

Though the installation of Ubuntu went like a charm but post install it was nothing but a lot of trouble all the while. The first problem I faced was the unity desktop with the login screen blank only with the wallpaper, mouse cursor, volume icon and power icon on the top. The users list was not visible at all. Adding to this the desktop was really slow, slow like hell. Hence removed Unity and installed GNOME which is much much better.

Though randomly my problems arose and got fixed by the million commands on the terminal given by me after reading websites and solutions on askubuntu until I decided to seek the help of experts here to stabilize it once for all.

I am a Masters student, with a project on robotics. The robotics software requires Ubuntu to work. Hence switched to Ubuntu. Also I work on Webgl and Blender which is also part of my project. When I say blender, the models made by me are fairly simple enough to only test my code but still I need it.

Though the machine was never performing at its best until yesterday when I installed the nvidia driver downloaded from the nvidia site itself. The link is [here](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/linux-display-ia32-173.14.36-driver-uk.html).

When I ran the .run file it went smooth and I was very glad to even see the nvidia splash  screen show up before the login - WOW. The login screen worked fine.

But to my dismay webgl was not working(it was never working) and also blender stopped working(was working fine all the time). At this stage except webgl and blender everything else in the desktop was fine (login screen fixed, system was uber cool fast with gnome, etc., )

Now I started the troubleshooting process to install webgl and fix the blender problem and eventually ended up screwing up the whole machine. Sorry to say but this is the truth. The truth is I had screwed up the video driver again when following the guidelines to fix the webgl and it blasted everything. I again tried to install the downloaded nvidia drivers but they refused to install because somehow my kernel was updated to 3.7 and had the driver now had problems. So degraded it to 3.5 and installed the drivers which was successful. Currently the state of my machine is

The problems now (solved the login problem temporarily by editing the /etc/gdm/custom.conf to do autologin)

1 - Login screen - Has Mouse Cursor, Wallpaper, icons on the top but the users list is not visible and neither the buttons. And it looks blank.

2 - Blender - Is now working fine

3 - Webgl - Is not working neither with chrome or firefox

I am glued to this machine from sterday without sleep, have not even gone home to have my food or anything else. My eyes are even refusing to open and to look at things clearly. So thought before I go into the REM mode will post this question so that souls out there can come to my aid.

Comment: Sounds like you managed to get 13.04 BETA, how you did though, I have no clue. Did you upgrade ever, or have anyone do something on your computer?

Comment: It is my University Lab machine. Hence do not know if someone had fiddled with it. So should I now do clean re-install of the machine with 12.10 again?

Comment: Please provide the output of `glxinfo` and `ldd /usr/bin/glxinfo` (the output sould be quite long, so use `pastebinit` (`command | pastebinit`) or paste.ubuntu.com). This should help to diagnose your problem.

Comment: output of glxinfo http://paste.ubuntu.com/5632343/

output of ldd /usr/bin/glxinfo http://paste.ubuntu.com/5632347/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friends,

Fixed the issue.

1 - Did a clean re-install of ubuntu 12.10

Started with the login screen problem first, but now i am not an amateur anymore so handled it with nomodeset.

2 - Unity was really slow. Yeah I know this so installed Gnome.

3 - Installed the NVIDIA*.173.14.36.run downloaded from Nvidia drivers website.

Lost the login screen again. But still with my windows laptop lying nearby found out the solution that I have add the following

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

The above line was taken from the article [here](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/)

After adding it to the repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The above fixed the problems

Now I am able to see and configure both monitors in the nvidia settings panel.

Also with a minor tweak with firefox using **about:config** in the address bar of firefox and changed two settings after which the webgl started working like charm(but a bit slow, which I am least bothered about)

```
webgl.force_enabled = true
webgl.min_capability_mode = true
```

(even if the above settings do not exist in your machine then add it yourself)

Installed blender works without any problems. Now I have left to do is install my robotic software from scratch again :-)